# Not able to integrate ionic with capacitor , npm throws error

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

I have a blank ionic project , I am trying to integrate with capacitor with ionic to build android app.

I run this command . `ionic capacitor add android` this throwing npm error please help me out to resolve this

> C:\Users\i\Rabi\learn\ilearn>ionic capacitor add android
>
> > ionic integrations enable capacitor
> > npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core npm WARN @ionic/angular-toolkit@4.0.0 requires a peer of
> > @angular-devkit/architect@^0.1200.0 but none is installed. You must
> > install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2
> > requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install
> > peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN The package @angular/compiler is
> > included as both a dev and production dependency. npm WARN optional
> > SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
> > npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
> > fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> > {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
> > DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13
> > (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN
> > notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
> > fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> > {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> - @capacitor/core@3.1.2 updated 1 package and audited 1639 packages in 20.453s
>
> 130 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities   run `npm audit fix` to fix
> them, or `npm audit` for details
>
> > npm.cmd i -D -E @capacitor/cli npm WARN @ionic/angular-toolkit@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/architect@^0.1200.0 but none is
> > installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
> > ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is
> > installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN The
> > package @angular/compiler is included as both a dev and production
> > dependency. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
> > fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING
> > OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted
> > {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
> > npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13
> > (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN
> > notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
> > fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> > {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> - @capacitor/cli@3.1.2 updated 1 package and audited 1639 packages in 17.196s
>
> 129 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities   run `npm audit fix` to fix
> them, or `npm audit` for details
>
> > capacitor.cmd init ilearn io.ionic.starter --npm-client npm error: unknown option '--npm-client' [ERROR] An error occurred while running
> > subprocess capacitor.
>
> ```
>     capacitor.cmd init ilearn io.ionic.starter --npm-client npm exited with exit code 1.
>
>     Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
> ```

I tried npm audit fix but no success

Answer (score 2):

`ionic capacitor add android` is used to add "android" in the ionic project, not to integrate capacitor.

To integrate capacitor you need to do these steps

`npm install @capacitor/core`

`npm install @capacitor/cli --save-dev`

`npx cap init`

Comment: thanks for the response, but i am more concern about the error and vulnerabilities

Comment: Capacitor 3.1.2 have some issue, So I moved back to capacitor 2, you can try with capacitor 2 with your app and check is it working or not?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

*Open VS Code and type*

1.ionic start

- If it ask any question just put these(no,React,myApp,sidemenu,no)

2.cd myApp => ionic build

3.npm install @capacitor/android

4.npx cap add android

5.npx cap open android

**Could not follow then watch this video**
Ionic Capacitor Tutorial - Ionic Build Android & Ionic Build iOS by
Code Swag